# How to ensure an accepted C++ template type to overload an operator?

Tags: c++, templates

I want to implement a class template:

```
template <typename Type>
class MyClass {/*...*/}
```

I want to force the `Type` accepted by `MyClass` to overload the `<` operator. How can I do that? It should be possible, because standard library is doing it for sorted containers. I don't want to use explicit template specialization and implement in `MyClass` for specific types. I want the `Type` to be responsible for that.

Answer (score 7):

The easy way is to just use it.  C++ templates are fully duck-typed and not very checked until you pass an actual type in.

You can use SFINAE based techniques to test things like that...

```
namespace details {
  template<template<class...>class Z, class, class...>
  struct can_apply:std::false_type{};
  template<class...>struct voider {using type=void;};
  template<class...Ts>using void_t=typename voider<Ts...>::type;
  template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply<Z, void_t<Z<Ts...>>, Ts...>:std::true_type{};
}
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
using can_apply = details::can_apply<Z,void,Ts...>;
```

this is a SFINAE helper that detects if you can apply a template to a pack of types.

```
template<class X, class Y=X>
using raw_less_r = decltype( std::declval<X>()<std::declval<Y>() );

template<class X, class Y=X>
using can_raw_less = can_apply<raw_less_r, X, Y>;
```

and now `can_raw_less<int>` is derived from `true_type` if `int < int` is valid, and `false_type` otherwise.

We then go off and:

```
template <typename Type, class=void>
class MyClass;

template <typename Type>
class MyClass<Type, std::enable_if_t<can_raw_less<Type>>>
{/*...*/}
```

use SFINAE and `enable_if_t` to create a specialization that exists if and only if `Type<Type` is valid.

Note that a better pattern is probably:

```
template<class F, class...Args>
using invoke_result = decltype( std::declval<F>()( std::declval<Args>()... ) );
template<class F, class...Args>
using can_invoke = can_apply< invoke_result, F, Args... >;

template<class Type, class Cmp=std::less<Type>>
class MyClass {
  static_assert( can_invoke< Cmp, Type const&, Type const& >{}, "You must be able to compare Type to itself" );
  // use Cmp{}(Type, Type) to compare
};
```

which is what std containers do, with the addition of a `static_assert` for cleaner error messages.

Comment: Or just use [`boost::has_less`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/has_less.html).

Comment: That is bound to scare any new comer :) A solution, nonetheless.

Comment: Thank you sir! That gets me start reading on some keywords here.

Answer (score 3):

If the implementation of `MyClass` uses the `<` operator on objects of `Type`, you don't have to do anything. The compiler will report an error if the operation is not supported.

If the implementation of `MyClass` does not use the `<` operator on objects of `Type`, then there is nothing to worry about.

In either case, there is nothing for you to do, other than documenting what's expected of `Type`.

Comment: Thank you very much sir!

Comment: But I see in container specifications operators like std::less<_Kty>. Why are they there?

Comment: @lulijeta, that allows use of `operator<` defined for a type automatically. However, it is possible to use a different method of ordering the items of a container by using a custom clas that can use different logic, such as `std::greater`.

Comment: You could detect if `<` is supported and generate an error if not, instead of the error spew you get if you don't do it explicitly.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont How do I detect whether a specific method or operator is not there?

Comment: @lulijeta Another answer added with that in it.

Answer (score 1):

Simple and readable using [boost::has_less](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/has_less.html) from [Boost.TypeTraits](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/type_traits/doc/html/index.html):

```
#include <boost/type_traits/has_less.hpp>

template <typename Type>
class MyClass {
    static_assert( boost::has_less<Type>::value, 
                   "Template parameter Type must be less-than-comparable" );  
};
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4fd54258139ae720)